# How can I write a Google Sheets query function that will sort a list that has a Letter and number properly?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, sql-order-by

In google sheets, I have a ton of data that needs to be sorted like this: P1, P2, P3, etc using a QUERY function. when I do an "ORDER BY" clause in my QUERY formula, it returns the list incorrectly putting P10 right after P1 as shown below

I got the list returned like this...

P1
P10
P2
P3
etc.

[screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DZqw.jpg)

How can I get it to sort properly so that P10 comes after P9 and so forth?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is entirely correct, it's just the consequence of how lexicographic ordering works with digits when the strings aren't all the same length. To get around this you need to split the column in two (one just containing the alphabetic portion, the other containing the numeric portion) and sort by both of those columns, OR use string manipulation to add padding zeroes to the number portion (i.e. make P1 into P01). There are various ways of doing all the above, and without any context it's difficult to state which is the most appropriate way for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you may try adding this `sort\regex` part to your working `QUERY` to get your expected output style.

```
=LAMBDA(z,SORT(z,--REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(z,,1),"\d+"),1))(QUERY({A2:B13},"Select * ORDER BY Col1"))
```

- Replace 1 in the `INDEX(z,,1)` with the appropriate column number of `P`  in your query output.

[image]